# Powershell - "InvokeMember" with "5" argument(s) Error

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I keep running into an InvokeMember with 5 arguments errors, but I believe it has to do with my path. I want to run this from any computer from any location the script folder is located.

```
$ScriptDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$ScriptName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name

Function Get-MsiDBVersion {
param (
    [string] $fn
)
try {
    $FullPath = (Resolve-Path $fn).Path 
    $windowsInstaller = New-Object -com WindowsInstaller.Installer
    $database = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "OpenDatabase","InvokeMethod", $Null, 
            $windowsInstaller, @($Fullpath, 0)
        )
    $q = "SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'"
    $View = $database.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "OpenView", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $database, ($q)
        )
    $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null) | Out-Null
    $record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null
        )
    $productVersion = $record.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "StringData", "GetProperty", $Null, $record, 1
        )
    $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Close", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null) | Out-Null
    return $productVersion
} catch {
    throw "Failed to get MSI file version the error was: {0}." -f $_
}
}

$Program = @{
Installer = "$ScriptDir\Program.exe"
Version = (get-item "$ScriptDir\Program.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion.TrimEnd()
Arguments = "/SILENT /ALLUSERS /NORESTART"
Exe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Program.exe"
ExeVersion = (Get-ChildItem $RegUninstall32 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where name -like "*program*" | Get-ItemProperty ).DisplayVersion
}
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and paste the exact error message.

Comment: what is the goal here - you want to receive information about installed msi packages?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

- You need to pass a *full, file-system-native* path to a `.msi` file to the `WindowsInstaller.Installer` COM object ([Windows Installer COM Automation interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/automation-interface-reference), given that PowerShell's current directory (location) usually differs from that of other in-process environments, namely .NET and the unmanaged processes used by COM.

  - While `$FullPath = (Resolve-Path $fn).Path` is an *attempt* to get the full path from a potentially relative one, it isn't *robust*, because the resolved path may be based on a *PowerShell-only* drive (created with `New-PSDrive`), which the outside world knows nothing about.
  - Instead, use [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) `-LiteralPath $fn`, which returns a *file-system-native* path, as known to all environments.
  - In either case, the resolving is based on the *current location*, as reflected in `$PWD` / `Get-Location`.
- There is no need to use *reflection* via `.GetType().InvokeMember()` in order to call the methods and access the properties of instances of the types exposed by the Windows Installer COM object - just call / access them *directly*, as usual. (In fact, I couldn't get your reflection-based code to work.)

Thus, the following should work:

```bash
Function Get-MsiDBVersion {
  param (
    [string] $LiteralPath
  )
  try {
    # Convert to a full, native path.
    $fullPath = Convert-Path -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath $LiteralPath
    $windowsInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
    $database = $windowsInstaller.Opendatabase($fullPath, 0)
    $q = "SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'"
    $view = $database.OpenView($q)
    $null = $View.Execute()
    $record = $View.Fetch()
    $productVersion = $record.StringData(1)
    $null = $View.Close()
    return $productVersion
  }
  catch {
    throw "Failed to get MSI file version; the error was: {0}." -f $_
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure currently what your goal here is, but if you want to receive information about MSIpackages you can do:

```
Get-CimInstance -query "select * from win32_product"
```

Your query won't work - your code:

```
$q = "SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'"
```

The syntax have to be:

```
"Select [Property] from [class] where [property] = [propertyvalue]"
```

e.g.:

```
get-ciminstance -query "select version,installState,Description,version,IdentifyingNumber from win32_product where Name = 'Blender'"
```

output:

```
Name                  : Blender
Version               : 2.82.1
InstallState          : 5
Caption               :
Description           : Blender
IdentifyingNumber     : {EDFAE2A8-E73B-4CD1-9648-46A7E4434BDA}
```

Comment: I am trying to compare versions of software in a file folder vs software installed and install newer versions if need be. This is the part where the script compiles the software list. It works if the location is a specified path on the C: drive, but I have a relative path and can’t get it to work.

Comment: so this is the issue for you: $FullPath = (Resolve-Path $fn).Path ? do you have a example where it fails?

Comment: Another way of putting it: The question is about inspecting `.msi` _files_ (in the context of which the query in the question _does_ work). You're solving a different problem.

Comment: it depends on the view... you want to update specific applications if a newer version is available. I did design several powershell based package distribution solutions. everytime we did define a json file per package which contained a so called detection rule, which detected if the software incl. version is installed, in the majority of the cases we did this check by validating registry and in very rare cases we had to check fileversions. in case of msi you can do this all by checking the registry... anyways this goes to far... seems i cant help you on this

Comment: (I'm not the OP, to be clear). Your answer does not address the question - neither as asked, nor with an alternative solution. In addition, it contains an incorrect statement: "Your query won't work", which indicates conceptual confusion. For the benefit of future readers, consider at least fixing that problem and providing context for your answer at the top (how it does / doesn't relate to the question).